# How to use varchar2 variable in XMLTable function?

Tags: oracle, varchar2, xmltable

I am trying to use XMLTable function as follow,

```
DECLARE IDs VARCHAR2(2000);

IDs := '4013105,4013106,4013107,4013108,4013109';

SELECT TO_NUMBER(COLUMN_VALUE) FROM XMLTABLE(:TRACT_IDS);
```

but getting this error

> PL/SQL: ORA-19102: XQuery string literal expected

If I use XMLTable with following example it runs successfully,

```
SELECT TO_NUMBER(COLUMN_VALUE) FROM XMLTABLE('4013105,4013106,4013107,4013108,4013109');
```

Please help in this regard..

Answer (score 0):

Do you like to do this?

```
DECLARE 
   IDs VARCHAR2(2000);
BEGIN
   IDs := '4013105,4013106,4013107,4013108,4013109';
   SELECT TO_NUMBER(COLUMN_VALUE) 
   BULK COLLECT INTO ...
   FROM XMLTABLE(IDs);
END;
```